# Server IP is pointing at some unknown (attacker) domain which has http. If I deny the http rule from ufw does that attacker site will be open?

Tags: nginx, ufw

My server IP is pointing to the two domains. One is pointed to my client's domain and other one is the annonymus/attacker. The attacker site has http. So if I apply ufw deny rule then will it stop using my site's data?

Like this:

```
sudo ufw deny from MyServerIP to any
```

I am just confused whether I should execute that deny command or not.